# Cannot return the img src path using php and wordpress customizer

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to create a theme in local environment, where in customizer I choose 3 images for a bootstrap carousel..Even if the customizer works the image source path is not showing..

in customizer I did:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('customizer_setting_one', array(
   'default' => '',
   'type' => 'theme_mod',
   'transport'         => 'refresh',
   'height'         => 325,
));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Upload_Control( $wp_customize, 'customizer_setting_one_control', array(
   'label'             => __('Slider Image #1'),
   'section'           => 'slideshow',
   'settings'          => 'customizer_setting_one',
   'mime_type' => 'image',
)));
```

and in my front-page.php

```
<img src="<?php echo (wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_theme_mod( 'customizer_setting_one_control', 'full' )[0] )); ?>" alt="Product 1">
```

But I get empty src img attribute.. Can anyone help please? thank you

Comment: What does `var_dump(get_theme_mod('customizer_setting_one_control', 'full'));` give you? Curious to know if `$attachment_id` is being passed through correctly or not.

Comment: It gives string(4) "full"

Comment: OK, what about `get_theme_mod('customizer_setting_one_control')` without other function argument?

Comment: No still, string(4) "full" and <img src="" alt="Product 3"> for <img src="<?php get_theme_mod('customizer_setting_one_control'); ?>" alt="Product 1">